# JavaScript module that uses AJAX to set and return variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write a module that makes two AJAX calls and sets variables to the results of those calls.  I'd like to be able to access the results  of those calls like `myModule.firstCall` and get the result of the AJAX call and not the promise.

```
var ajaxModule = (function () {
    var subFolderData = {},
        rootData = {};

    var subFolderFile = function () {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'Content/testData.json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    var rootFile = function () {
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'testDataRoot.json',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
        //only returning promise here, how to return $.when the call is done?
    return {
        rootFile: rootFile().done(function (data) {
            subFolderData = data;
        }),
        subFolderFile: subFolderFile().done(function (data) {
            rootData = data;
        })
    }
})();
//this prints out the dat as expected, but can I store the results in a variable
//to be accessed like ajaxModule.rootFile?
console.log(ajaxModule.rootFile.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}));
```

Comment: Try setting async to false

Comment: @ReeceJHayward I'm looking for it to be done async, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you [cannot `return` the result from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572).

Assigning them to a global (or higher-scope) variable, such as `subFolderData` or `rootData` in your example, is possible, but does not make sense because you do not know when the value will be available.

Storing the promises for the values, like your `ajaxModule.subFolderFile` and `ajaxModule. rootFile`, and always incorporating them when needing to access the data, is the way to go.

Comment: so, if i want to store the results of an AJAX call and use it in multiple places in my application i'll always have to do something like `myVar.done(callback)?` i was hoping there might be prettier syntax than that

Comment: Yes, you always need a callback. However, a) if your whole application depends on the results you can put the whole code in the callback, where you access `data` multiple times b) you've got the full power of composing promises available